# How to use split with "\" in UFT one (VB script)?

Tags: vbscript

I'm making a function to get the path for a file and if it doesn't exist, create the file or all the files in the path.

For that I'm trying to get all the files using split, but it doesn't work.

My code is:

> StrPath = "C:\Documents\Test"
>
> strFile = strPath.split("\")

It doesn't work, I tried using "\" but still failing.

Help, please

Comment: Split returns an array, not a string. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0764e5w5(v=vs.84)).

Comment: Don't use Split. Use GetFileName. Here's an [example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-extract-just-the-file-name-from-the-full-path-to-the-file/).